# Fragment onClick call method

Tags: java, android

I want to call a method `onClickTest` when I click anywhere in the fragment.

**Activity layout:**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:onClick="onClickTest"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Method in corresponding activity:**

```
public void onClickTest(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onClickTest");
}
```

The problem is that the method is never called when I click on the fragment. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: onClick called only on the activity which contains this fragment

Comment: @OuailBellal The activity contains this fragment.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can give an onClickListener to the frame layout which holds the fragment.

```
frameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener{
@Override
public abstract void onClick (View v){
//Your action
}
});
```

Comment: So it is not possible to use `android:onClick` inside `<fragment>` tag?

Comment: No ,fragment does not extend the View class

Answer (score 0):

Define onClick on your activity :

```
YourFragment mFragment;

public void onClickTest(View view) {
   mFragment.onClickTest(view);
}
```